# ASP.NET MVC 5: HttpContext.Session.Abandon() doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

is it possible that the Abandon() method doesn't exist in MVC 5 or is there a special import needed? Right now my logout method uses:

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear()
```

Is Abandon() still usable or is Clear() the only thing i can use in MVC 5?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 var currentSession = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
 currentSession.Abandon();
```

Comment: Hi, @Sajeetharan this doesnt work for me System.Web has no HttpContext